# Detect simbols in react js is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How are you?
So I'm trying do a calculator that It is possible to enter numbers from the keyboard and from the screen itself.
Using the numbers on the screen works well, however when trying to capture the numbers that are typed by the user via the keyboard, the symbols are not being captured.
I installed some consoles to try to understand what is happening but I couldn't and I would like to know if any of you can help me. I noticed that in the console console.log("o number digit é", numberDigit);, numberDigit is not returning but I can't understand why this is happening and as a result, I can't understand how to solve it
Thank you

```jsx
export default function Calculadora() {
  const [numberDigit, setNumberDigit] = useState("");
  const [isResult, setIsResult] = useState(false);
  const [lastCharIsOperator, setLastCharIsOperator] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    console.log(event.key);
    console.log(numberDigit);
    if (/^\d$/.test(event.key)) {
      handleAddNumber(event.key);
      console.log("estou no if da handleAddNumber");
      console.log("o number digit é", numberDigit);
    } else {
      if (/^[+\-*\/=Cc\n\r]$/.test(event.key)) {
        handleAddSimbol(event.key);
      }
      if (event.key === "Enter" || event.key === "Return") {
        evaluateExpression(numberDigit);
      }
    }
  };

  function handleAddNumber(number) {
    if (numberDigit && !isResult) {
      setNumberDigit((prevNumberDigit) => prevNumberDigit.concat(number));
    } else {
      setNumberDigit(number);
      setIsResult(false);
    }
  }

  function evaluateExpression(expression) {
    const regex = /^\d+[\+\-\*\/]\d+$/;
    const result = eval(expression);

    if (!lastCharIsOperator && !regex.test(expression)) {
      setNumberDigit(
        "Expressão inválida. Limpe a calculadora e refaça a expressão"
      );
      setIsResult(true);
      return;
    }

    if (expression.includes("/0")) {
      setNumberDigit("Divisão por zero não é permitida");
      setIsResult(true);
      return;
    } else {
      setNumberDigit(result.toString());
      setIsResult(false);
      console.log(result);
    }
  }

  function handleAddSimbol(simbol) {
    if (simbol === "=") {
      console.log(numberDigit);
      evaluateExpression(numberDigit);
    } else if (simbol === "C" || simbol === "c") {
      setNumberDigit("");
      setIsResult(false);
    } else if (numberDigit) {
      setNumberDigit((prevNumberDigit) => prevNumberDigit + simbol);
      setIsResult(false);
      setLastCharIsOperator(/^[+\-*\/]$/.test(simbol));
    }
  }

  const numbers = ["7", "8", "9", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3", "0"];
  const simbols = ["/", "*", "+", "-"];
  return (
    <main className="mainClass">
      <h1>{numberDigit}</h1>
      <div className="container">
        {numbers.map((number) => (
          <button
            className="item"
            onClick={() => handleAddNumber(number)}
            key={number}
          >
            {number}
          </button>
        ))}
        {simbols.map((simbol) => (
          <button
            className="simbols"
            onClick={() => {
              handleAddSimbol(simbol);
            }}
            key={simbol}
          >
            {simbol}
          </button>
        ))}
        <button
          className="ac-button"
          onClick={() => {
            handleAddSimbol("C");
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          C{" "}
        </button>
        <button
          className="equal-button"
          onClick={() => {
            handleAddSimbol("=");
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          ={" "}
        </button>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```